# How to set logger output path to directory which is provided by a service?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a symfony 3.2 project and want to log to a configurable directory. This directory is configured as a registry key in the Windows Registry (I cannot change that).

So I have built a service that reads the log path from the registry key, and now want to log to that path. This service does not need a logger, of course :-)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually depends on how and what you want to log.

Generally speaking, if you want to define another path for the logging of your application, your best bet is to do in the [AppKernel.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/3.2/app/AppKernel.php#L43)

Nothing prevent you to override this method in your own `AppKernel` and use PHP code to fetch the path in the Windows Registry, no need for a Symfony `service`.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, although I still needed the service - the actual method of fetching the log directory depends on the platform the application is running on. But the instantiation of the service is simple enough to do it manually in the `AppKernel.php`.

Comment: yup, I reworded to Symfony service to make a clear distinction between the both. Nothing wrong to encapsulate the complexity of the path discovery into a standalone class.

Answer (score 1):

You should call your service function with the expression language:

```
# app/config/config.yml
services:
    log_writer:
        class:        AppBundle\Log\LogWriter
        arguments:    ["@=service('log_reader').getLogDirectory()"]
```

Check out the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/expression_language.html).

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, but I've learned about the expression syntax - thanks! The problem could be, that I want to have the expression under the config key `monolog.handlers.<myhandler>.path`, where expressions don't seem to be evaluated.